# Ext plugin for Liferay 6.0.6 is not executed on RHEL 5.2 x86_64

Tags: java, jboss, centos, liferay-6

This is a strange problem . 
The Ext plugin for Liferay 6.0.6 can be executed on any OS platform but centos or RHEL.

Now I will try my best to explain my experiment.

First, I create a `login-hook` where a captcha image is added on `$LIFERAY_SDK_DIR/hooks/login-hook/docroot/custom-jsps/html/portlet/login/login.jsp`:

```
<portlet:actionURL windowState="<%= LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>" var="captchaURL">
                <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/captcha" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<liferay-ui:captcha url="<%= captchaURL %>" />
```

and also make a modification on `/html/taglib/ui/captcha/simplecaptcha.jsp` :

```
<div class="taglib-captcha">
    <table border=0>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <aui:input label="text-verification" name="captchaText" size="10" type="text" value="" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:10px;">
                <img id="captcha_image" alt="captcha" class="captcha" src="<%= url %>"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="captcha_change_btn" class="captcha"
                   onclick="return false;"><liferay-ui:message key="change_captcha" />
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <aui:script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(function ($) {
              $('#captcha_change_btn').click(function () {
                 var url = "<%= url %>";
                 $('#captcha_image').attr('src', url + '&random=' + Math.random());
              });
        });
    </aui:script>
</div>
```

After deploying the `login-hook` onto liferay, the login window will look like this: 
[image]

Second, I create a `login-ext` which will check the captcha text provided by user while logging in . So I add the code

```
    _log.warn("check the captcha ... ");
    CaptchaUtil.check(actionRequest);
    System.out.println("success check captcha");
```

in `protected void login(
            ThemeDisplay themeDisplay, ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse, PortletPreferences preferences)
        throws Exception` of `$LIFERAY_EXT_DIR/ext/login-ext/docroot/WEB-INF/ext-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/login/action/LoginAction.java`

Deploy the `login-ext`, then try to login without providing a captcha text will causes an error which is correct. But when I move the whole liferay system onto centos 5.8, login without a captcha text will be passed.

Could anyone give me a suggestion ? 
Thx

Comment: Does anyone understand what i mean ?

Comment: it works fine. thanks.. Is there any way to change style of image like other captcha??